# In Autofac, how do you register the Owned<B> relationship when A is a single instance and B is registered using InstancePerRequest?

Tags: c#, autofac, autofac-configuration

I am using Autofac version 3.5.2.

I want to register a singleton class A that needs B until some point in the future.  How do you do this if B is registered using `InstancePerRequest`?

Using `Owned<B>` directly does not work because the per request lifetime scope does not exist.  You get the `DependencyResolutionException` as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qMA6Kg).

One solution is to make A have a direct dependency on `ILifetimeScope`.  A begins a scope with the `MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag` when it needs an instance of B.

```
    using (var scope = this.lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
    {
        var b = scope.Resolve<B>();
        b.DoSomething();
    }
```

I do not like this approach since it is the service locator pattern.  See this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NCrIvm).

A second solution is to register B as `InstancePerRequest` and in the correct owned scope for B.  Registering B would look like this:  `builder.RegisterType<B>().InstancePerRequest(new TypedService(typeof(B)));`
The full example is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jGBl7T).

I like the second solution better but it also has problems:

1. It feels like a code smell that when registering B’s dependencies that they have to know to register themselves in B’s owned scope.
2. It does not scale well when B has a lot of dependencies and those dependencies have dependencies etc.  All these dependencies need the extra registration as in problem 1 above.

How would you recommend solving this problem? Thanks for the help.

#### Update

I have moved the `OwnedPerRequest<T>` related code into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41163598/4320302) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on [Nicholas' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124154/in-autofac-how-do-you-register-the-ownedb-relationship-when-a-is-a-single-ins#comment69263675_41006508) 
and his blog post on [IRegistrationSource](https://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/declarative-context-adapters-autofac2/)

It is based on the existing [`Owned<T>` class](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/src/Autofac/Features/OwnedInstances/Owned.cs) 
and its [registration source](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/master/src/Autofac/Features/OwnedInstances/OwnedInstanceRegistrationSource.cs).

```
public class OwnedPerRequest<T> : Owned<T>
{
    public OwnedPerRequest(T value, IDisposable lifetime) : base(value, lifetime) { }
}

public class OwnedPerRequestInstanceRegistrationSource : IRegistrationSource
{
    public IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration> RegistrationsFor(Service service, Func<Service, IEnumerable<IComponentRegistration>> registrationAccessor)
    {
        if (service == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
        if (registrationAccessor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(registrationAccessor));

        var swt = service as IServiceWithType;
        if (swt == null
             || !(swt.ServiceType.IsGenericType
                    && swt.ServiceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(OwnedPerRequest<>)))
            return Enumerable.Empty<IComponentRegistration>();

        var ownedInstanceType = swt.ServiceType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var ownedInstanceService = swt.ChangeType(ownedInstanceType);

        return registrationAccessor(ownedInstanceService)
            .Select(r =>
            {
                var rb = RegistrationBuilder.ForDelegate(swt.ServiceType, (c, p) =>
                {
                    var lifetime = c.Resolve<ILifetimeScope>().BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag);
                    try
                    {
                        var value = lifetime.ResolveComponent(r, p);
                        return Activator.CreateInstance(swt.ServiceType, value, lifetime);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        lifetime.Dispose();
                        throw;
                    }
                });

                return rb
                    .ExternallyOwned()
                    .As(service)
                    .Targeting(r)
                    .CreateRegistration();
            });
    }

    public bool IsAdapterForIndividualComponents => true;

    public override string ToString() => "OwnedPerRequestInstanceregistrationSource";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is inject a `Func<Owned<B>>` which you invoke when you need a B. This removes the service locator pattern and I'm pretty sure is identical to this in functionality to this

```
using (var scope = this.lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope(MatchingScopeLifetimeTags.RequestLifetimeScopeTag))
{
    var b = scope.Resolve<B>();
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

If you inject a `Func<Owned<B>>` the usage would look like this:

```
public void DoSomethingThatUsesB()
{
    //_bFactory is your Func<Owned<B>>
    using(var b = _bFactory.Invoke())
    {
         ... (use b)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XxGKlk) what you had in mind?  If so, it throws the `DependencyResolutionException`.

Comment: The `DoSomethingThatUsesB` should only be invoked inside of a web request if it is registered as `InstancePerRequest` (InstancePerRequest is typically used in web applications), I think you want to register the B as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` which should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

If the lifetime structure of your app is quite simple (i.e. you don't nest further lifetime scopes under "request" that need to resolve the shared `B`), then you might just switch `B` to `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`:

```
builder.RegisterType<B>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

This will be largely equivalent to per-request, but will also allow the `Owned<B>` to be successfully resolved by a singleton.

The only caveat is that you have to be careful not to accidentally take a dependency on `B` from singletons elsewhere, since this will no longer be detected as an error. It's possible to protect against this using a custom `IComponentLifetime` but probably not worth the effort unless you do it a lot.

Comment: Thank you, Nicholas.  What about if you don’t have access to change the registration?  For example, the components in the `AutofacWebTypesModule`.

Comment: In that case you will need to use your first possible solution (`ILifetimeScope`)

Comment: Interesting code! Looks like it might be a workable option, too. Cheers!